# Django: oldest entry for distinct fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models (simplified for sample purposes):

```
class Execution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=30)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('code', 'secondary_code', 'execution')

    code = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=30)
    secondary_code = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=3)
    execution = models.ForeignKey(Execution, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

On the database I have the following instances:

```
execution_1 = Execution('Execution 1', '2019-01-01')
execution_2 = Execution('Execution 2', '2019-01-02')

post_1 = Post('123', '456', execution_1, 'lorem')
post_2 = Post('789', '999', execution_1, 'ipsum')
post_3 = Post('789', '999', execution_2, 'dolor')
```

I want to retrieve all the posts, unique for `code` and `secondary_code` (so, only one between `post_2` and `post_3` since they have the same `code` and `secondary_code`) and chose the one to get based on the oldest `execution` (so, in this case, I want `post_1` and `post_2` since the `execution` of `post_2` is older that the `execution` of `post_3`).

I need to support both Postgres and sqlite3 3.18.0, so, because of sqlite, I cannot use window functions.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
newer_post = Post.objects.filter(code=OuterRef('code'), 
    secondary_code=OuterRef('secondary_code'), 
    execution__creation_date__gt=OuterRef('execution_dt'), 
)

posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(execution_dt=execution__creation_date, )

latest_posts = posts.\
    annotate(has_newer_post=Exists(newer_post), ).\
    filter(has_newer_post=False, )
```